# Whats the significance of hostname in SIP uri format

Tags: uri, sip

I have a SIP call scenario with

```
  user1@host1.com:5060 is in call with user2@host2.com:5060
```

now later on we have another call wherein

```
  user3@host1.com:5060 calls up user1@host2.com:5060
```

As can be seen user1 with host1.com is the caller  in the first call and user1 with host2.com is the callee in the second call. Is this possible to associate a username (or a SIP phone number which is unique) with 2 different hosts.

Would this create a call waiting scenario and if yes what ideally should happen to the first call if user1 doesn't take any action when it hears the call wait beep when user3 calls.

Answer (score 0):

SIP has the concept of an "address of record", the URI that appears in From and To headers. These indicate who you are. Contact headers, in contrast show "where" you are - they indicate the address of a user agent.

There is no relationship between username and domain, as far as the protocol is concerned.

In this case `sip:user1@host2.com:5060` and `sip:user2@host2.com:5060` have no relationship to each other, beyond possibly sharing some infrastructure.

It's perfectly possible to have different domains have users with the same name. (The same applies to email addresses - `postmaster@example.com` and `postmaster@example2.com`, for instance.)

In the example above, I see no reason why there would be a call waiting scenario. (You could *construct* a setup where all usernames on a `host2.com` referenced the same useragent, perhaps a LAN only setup. In such a setup, all calls to any user on `host2.com` would route to the same user agent. If the agent only supported one call, you could have a call waiting scenario.)